# How to visualise this data in a Splunk dashboard?

Tags: splunk, splunk-query, splunk-dashboard

The final data from Splunk I have is in the form of a csv file with about 180 rows (product/goods) and a column that records the change (in sales compared to the previous month).

```
Product   mean   variance 
Apples  increase no change
Oranges decrease decrease
bananas no change no change 
corn increase increase 
spinach increase increase
```

I want to create a dashboard to get a sense of the above table . What is the best visual representation of the above?
Any example would be very beneficial!

Comment: So far, I figured that the solution would be similar to the examples from the splunk 6.x dashboard example app.  (https://splunkbase.splunk.com/app/1603/)